# При клике добавить атрибут input'u

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть обычный `input`

```
<input type="text" name="bin" placeholder="" class="order_input">
```

Есть радиокнопки, где при нажатии на одно виден этот Input, при нажатии на вторую скрывается.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( ".individual" ).click(function() {
              $( ".requi" ).slideUp(500);
            });
            $( ".legal" ).click(function() {
              $( ".requi" ).slideDown(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Как сделать так что при нажатии добавлялся атрибут `required` к `input` и также убирался при нажатии на другую радиокнопку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Твоя задача решается такими строками:

**Добавляет атрибут:**

```
$('.order_input').prop('required', true);
```

**Убирает атрибут:**

```
$('.order_input').prop('required', false);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var requi = $('.requi');
  var input = $('.order_input');
  $( ".individual" ).click(function() {
    input.prop('required', true); // <<==
    requi.slideUp(500);
  });
  $( ".legal" ).click(function() {
    input.prop('required', false); // <<==
    requi.slideDown(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="bin" placeholder="" class="order_input">

<button class="individual">individual</button>
<button class="legal">legal</button>
```

Comment: Класс только поправь где убирает атрибут на false.

Answer (score 1):

#### Добавление и удаление атрибута:

**jQuery**:

```
$('selector').attr('attrName', 'value');
$('selector').removeAttr('attrName');
```

**Аналог нативно**:

```
element.addAttribute('attrName', 'value');
element.removeAttribute('attrName');
```

---

#### Добавление и удаление ключа на элементе (property):

**jQuery**:

```
$('selector').prop('propertyName', value);
```

**Нативно**:

```
element['propertyName'] = value;
```

---

#### В итоге выйдет:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".individual" ).click(function() {
         $( ".requi" ).prop('required', true).slideUp(500);
    });
    $( ".legal" ).click(function() {
         $( ".requi" ).prop('required', false).slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: disabled и readonly через prop() включаются.

Comment: Да, поторопился.